# How can I parse newline-delimited data in Bash while preserving empty strings?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've posted a similar question before but I'm confused by all the workarounds people have with `awk` and `IFS`

I'm using `snmpbulkwalk` to get a string of data. SNMP utils normally return the requested data as a String separated with newline carriers between each value.

I'm getting anywhere from 0 to 300+ values as a single string. Each value is followed by a newline carrier. In the case where SNMP is given an empty string from its target it concatenates the newline carrier to the empty string and adds it to the data that will be passed back. I could get

> 10.1.1.1\n10.1.1.2\n10.1.1.3\n10.1.1.4\n    (four values)
>
> as well as
>
> \n\n10.1.1.3\n10.1.1.4\n\n\n\n10.1.1.8\n\n   (nine values)

Previously I was using this to parse the data:

```
IP=`echo $IP | tr "\n" " "`
IP=( $IP )
```

The code above would remove *all* newlines. If I used the code snippet it would return

> String 1: {"10.1.1.1", "10.1.1.2", "10.1.1.3", "10.1.1.4"}
>
> String 2: {"10.1.1.3", "10.1.1.4", "10.1.1.8"}

String 1 was parsed correctly into an array but String 2 was not. I need it to be:

> String 2: {"", "", "10.1.1.3", "10.1.1.4", "", "", "", "10.1.1.8", ""}

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: BTW -- have you looked at the `paste` command? I wonder if `paste -d, <(smpbulwalk ... FOO) <(snmpbulwalk ... BAR)` might do what you want, with no fancy bash scripting needed.

Comment: (btw, in general, `array=( $string )` is bad practice; it performs not only string-splitting, but also glob-expansion -- so if any component emitted from the string-splitting phase can be read as a glob, that glob gets expanded; it's in a much better habit to use `read -a` reflexively when you want to split a string into an array).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'll remember not to reference it in the future. I have yet to have any official Bash training so it's mostly been "research and adapt" . . . which as you can see leads to a lot of bad usage

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ are good places to start for content that's been reviewed for best practices.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't used Bash often enough to explore it in detail. This should be a good place start off on the right foot. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [BashFAQ #001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for best practices on reading from either files or streams in bash. If you need to read contents into an array, that may look like the following:

```
results=( )                       # declare the empty array
while IFS= read -r line; do       # loop over input lines...
  results+=( "$line" )            # ...appending just-read line to the array
done < <(snmpbulkwalk ...)        # ...reading output from snmpbulkwalk
declare -p results                # print the array's contents
```

...or, using the bash 4.0 `mapfile` command (or its synonym `readarray`) to get the same result:

```
readarray -t results < <(snmpbulwalk ...)
declare -p results # print the array's contents
```

...after which you can either iterate over `"${snmp_results[@]}"` or look at `"${#snmp_results[@]}"` to get the number of lines and index in.

---

That latter case is likely to be exceptionally useful to you here, since you can then read two results into two different arrays and index into them in parallel.

```
readarray -t snmp_results_FOO < <(snmpbulwalk ... FOO)
readarray -t snmp_results_BAR < <(snmpbulwalk ... BAR)
for idx in "${!snmp_results_FOO[@]}"; do
  printf '%s,%s\n' "${snmp_results_FOO[$idx]}" "${snmp_results_BAR[$idx]}"
done
```

Comment: Ok, so sorry about that! See if the edit makes it easier to understand

Comment: I read your edit, and frankly, I don't see any respect in which I need to change my answer for it to remain applicable and correct.

Comment: Ok! If that's the case I'll give it a go. So by your response, `IFS= read -r line` is saying to get the field and stop at the default whitespace delimiter set, handle the data as I've coded, then return to the start of the loop and get the next field? And this preserves an empty string as a valid value?

Comment: *nod*; your interpretation is correct. I've made some minor changes just to make it easier to demonstrate the behavior in play, but not changing actual semantics.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry again about all the confusion. I'll implement the second solution and check the results

Comment: By the way -- which version of bash are you targeting? `readarray` is a 4.0 addition; if you're on 3.2, you'll need to use the `while read` loop.

Comment: It's 4.0 on my sandbox device